# VLookup General MultiItem Search

Tags: excel, vlookup

So, I have a list of products that I want to generalize in a list of items that we purchase each with a sell price (with other data such as profit margin, though not relevant).
Lets say, for example:

Twix $2

Hershey's $2

Snickers $2

Next, I want to make a price list based on these, but I want to combine them into one generalized item "Candy Bars" and display the price.

Now, this is a small corner shop in a hotel, and we have lots of items to sell and a few items we want to generalize and fit into a one sheet price list.

My question is: How can I streamline this so I can use a funtion (I'm thinking VLookup), to display the price based on the generalized name?

I have tried to put the items in a "Defined Name" but I seem to be getting an error from the #N/A

`=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A14," ",""), ProfitList,4, FALSE)`

Where A14 is Candy Bars and the defined name is CandyBars. 4 is the column of the table where the Sell Price is

EDIT:

[image: Image to show, hopefully, what I'm looking for]

Comment: Is ProfitList a named range of cells? If so, what's the range?

Comment: ProfitList is a table from another sheet: from A4:F68.

PriceList is on a separate sheet.

Comment: Column A in this table should have a cell with value "CandyBars". This value exists in column A?

Comment: Sheet1 Column A in that table is a list of individual items we sell along with profits and other info. Sheet2 Column A, the Price list has a cell with the value CandyBars. I want to take, for example, the 3 items in the example, put them in say, an array, and display the price (even if it just picks the first item from that array)

Comment: You are looking up the text "CandyBars" whereas it appears you want to refer to a range with that name so you will probably need INDIRECT.

Comment: Edited: Added an image to hopefully show a visual of what I'm wanting. Unfortunately, using INDIRECT yielded an error #REF

Comment: What is the function of sheet 2? The way it looks to me is sheet 2 you have a drop List and as you choose the item in the list the cell to the right changes to get the listed price.

Comment: The price sheet (sheet 2) is a list of items generalized. All candy typs go under candy bad, sodas go into either bottled soda or canned soda. It's a list to be printed out and posted so the customer can see it. The function above in the question is what's on sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you want sheet 2 to have a dropdown List and as you choose the item in the list the cell to the right changes to get the listed price. Then answer can be:

- =FILTER( price_array, item_name_array = item_name)
- =XLOOKUP( item_name, item_name_array, price_array)

To get the dropdown menu

1. Go to Data>Data Validation>Data Validation...
2. In Settings Allow: choose list and select the item_name_array.

You said:

> I want to combine them into one generalized item "Candy Bars" and display the price.

In this situation you want to place a function on the filter like average(), sum(), min(), or max().

- =AVERAGE(FILTER( price_array, generalized_array = generalized_name))